# file paging when insert 1 byte early in file

Tags: linux-kernel

what happens when i open a 100 MB file, and insert 1 byte somewhere near the beginning, then save it? does the Linux kernel literally shift everything back 1 byte (thus altering every page), & then re-saves every byte after the insertion? that seems highly inefficient!

or i suppose the kernel could insert a 1-byte page just to hold this insertion, but i've never heard of that happening. i thought all pages had to be a standard size (e.g., 4 KB or 4 MB but not 1 byte)

i have checked in numerous linux/OS bks (bovet/cesati, kerrisk, tanenbaum), & have played around with the kernel code a bit, and can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that OSes *don't* typically allow you to insert an arbitrary number of bytes at an arbitrary position within a file.  Your analysis shows why - it just isn't an efficient operation on the typical implementation of a file.

Normally you can only add or remove bytes at the end of a file.